# why are numpy arrays printed like this?

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

Take for example generating random a 7x5x3 RGB image.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a random 7x5x3 RGB image
image = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(7, 5, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Visualize the image
plt.imshow(image)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

print(image)       # ???
```

output:

```
array([[[217, 109,  51],
        [104, 223, 252],
        [235,  88, 220],
        [196,  73,  58],
        [ 33, 198,  11]],

       [[103,  71, 247],
        [ 77, 251, 147],
        [109,  81, 172],
        [ 67, 157,  56],
        [222,  49,  18]],

        ...
```

To my understanding, an 7x5x3 RGB image is simply a 7x5 2D array with 3 channels. I would imagine 3 2D-arrays tranposed ontop of each other. However, when I go to print this image, it shows an 5x3 2D array repeated 7 times.

Shouldn't the structure of the array not look more like the output: `np.zeros((3,7,5))`?

Comment: We don't have 3D screens. So a 3D numpy array is printed as a bunch of 2D arrays sequentially.

Comment: Why do you expect it to be like `np.zeros((3,7,5))`. It's like `np.zeros(7,5,3)`

Comment: Your example `zeros` has `size=(3,7,5)` but your own array has `size=(7,5,3)`

Comment: yes this display can be a bit awkward for images like this, but numpy is a generalized n-d array package, and makes the leading dimensions 'outermost' (at least in the default c order).  Images are best shown with image software, not  a 'raw' array form.

Comment: MATLAB is f order, with trailing dim outer most.  It displays as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you're expecting.  `numpy` doesn't understand "channels".  It understands 3D arrays.  The outer array has 7 elements.  That display shows `image[0]`, which is a 5x3 array, 5 rows of 3 elements each, and `image[1]`, in the same format.  You are showing 10 pixels there.  Even image files do not store the 3 planes separately -- the color components are interleaved.

If, for some reason, you want the red plane by itself, do `red = image[:,:,0]`.  That produces a 7x5 array.